# Change in Form UI in iOS 14 for SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14, xcode12

After building my SwiftUI for iOS 14 I've noticed that a lot of alignments were broken in forms.

Now each section seems to be in a rectangle with rounded corners and extra padding. It looks great on devices with large screens, but on smaller screens everything is cluttered and there is barely any space to display the content.

[image]

[Looking around](https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/i0d7xm/did_swiftui_form_change/) this seems to be a voluntary UI change from Apple, but I can't find a way to revert it since it doesn't work with my current layout.

Is this a known change in the default UI? Can I revert back to the way it was in iOS13 or do I have to rebuild everything on my own and not use a `Form` view?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's the new default style but you could change your `Form` to a `List` and apply the `listStyle` modifier in order to get the old look:

```
List {
    //...
}
.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with Forms, List only.